# adding the sum of neighbors in a matrix and making a new matrix

Tags: c, matrix

I have the part about adding up the sum of neighbors in a matrix, the part where I'm stuck is making it work for as many matrices specified in `int gen = numberofgenerationshere;`
I can only make it work for the first two, and in the case of 4 generations in my code, it works for gen 4 but not gen 3. Also, the rules that have to be applied to it and then moved into the next matrix only apply `else if(sum < 50){grid2[i][j] += 3;}`. I've been working on this for 2 days and I'm no closer to how it should be done. Also, I know I shouldn't use global variables but that what we were told to do.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

#define ROWS 3
#define COLS 3

int seed = 7;
int high = 30;
int gen = 4;
int grid1[ROWS][COLS];     
int grid2[ROWS][COLS];       
int tempGrid[ROWS][COLS];          
int size = sizeof grid1 / sizeof *grid1;

void printArray(int grid[][COLS], int row, int col){
  for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    printf("\n");
    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
      printf("%3d ", grid[i][j]);
    }
  }
  printf("\n\n");
}

void fillGrid(int grid[][COLS], int row, int col){

  srand(seed);

  for(int i = 0; i < row; i++){
    for(int j = 0; j < col; j++){
      grid[i][j] = rand() % high;
    }
  }
}

int sumOfNeighbors(int grid[][COLS], int row, int col, int count){
  int i, j, sum = 0, num = 0;

  for(i = row - 1; i <= row + 1; i ++){
    for(j = col - 1; j <= col + 1; j++){
      if( i >= 0 && i <= size - 1 && j >= 0 && j <= size - 1){
        sum += grid[i][j];
        //printf("SUM: %d\n", sum);
      }
    }
  }

  //printf("\n\nSUM2: %d\n\n", sum);

  memcpy(grid2, grid1, ROWS*COLS*sizeof(int));

  for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
    for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){
      if(sum % 10 == 0){
        grid2[i][j] = 0;
      }
      else if(sum < 50){
        grid2[i][j] += 3;      
      }
      else if(sum > 50 && sum < 150){
        if(sum <= 0){
          grid2[i][j] = 0;
        }
        else{
          grid2[i][j] -= 3;
        }
      }
      else{
        grid2[i][j] = 1;
      }
    }
  }
  return sum;
}

void createNewGrid(int grid[][COLS], int row, int col){
  int count = 1;
  int k, i, j, num = 0;

  for(k = 0; k < gen; k++){
    for(i = 0; i < ROWS; i++){
      for(j = 0; j < COLS; j++){   
        num = sumOfNeighbors(grid, i, j, count);
      }
    }
    
    
    if(count % 2 == 1){
      printf("----GEN %d----\n", count);
      printArray(grid, ROWS, COLS);
     // memcpy(grid2, grid1, ROWS*COLS*sizeof(int));
    }
    else{
      printf("----GEN %d----\n", count);
      printArray(grid2, ROWS, COLS);
      memcpy(grid1, grid2, ROWS*COLS*sizeof(int));
    }
    count ++;
  }
}


int main(){
  /*
  int count = 1;
  int num = 0;
  */

  fillGrid(grid1, ROWS, COLS);

  createNewGrid(grid1, ROWS, COLS);
}
```

Comment: Can you explain what you are trying to do with `grid1` and `grid2`?

Comment: Consider this condition `else if(sum > 50 && sum < 150){ ... }`. How could it possibly be `if(sum <= 0){` inside it?

Comment: @scottHunter sorry, my idea was that the original matrix is in grid1, then grid2 is updated with the new values from grid1. So the first entry in grid1 is 27. the neighbors add up to 42, so add 3 to 27, put 30 in grid2. then the next time around, grid2 is used to put the new values in grid1.

Comment: @Bob__ because I'm a ding dong. Thanks, that's fixed.

Comment: Can you explain how this code is trying to implement what you want to do with `grid1` & `grid2`?